# Unable to remove focus/blur on md-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I created a directive so I can focus and un focus on md-select. The directive works on foucsing on the element however the blur function does not.

```
 class FocusMeDirective {
      constructor() {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = { trigger: '@focusMe' };
      }
      controller($scope, $element, $timeout) {
        'ngInject';
        $scope.$watch('trigger', (value) => {
          if (value.toString() === 'true') {
            $timeout(() => {
              $element[0].focus();
            });
          }
          if (value.toString() === 'false') {
            console.log('unfoucs');
            $timeout(() => {
              $element[0].blur();
            });
          }
        });
      }
}
```